# Make eax = 1 using two bytes(intel)

Tags: assembly

This question may sound weird, but it's needed for injecting code to a binary.

Can you think of a way to make eax equal to 1, without depending on content like carry flag or others, other registers etc ?

But in 2 bytes only. 3 is easy and it can be done in many ways, but can it be done with 2 ?

Comment: You mean two bytes, not two opcodes, right?

Comment: You should also specify the architecture. In x86_64 this is impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you mean 2 bytes, not 2 opcodes. If you really mean 2 opcodes, then the following 3-byte alternatives come to mind:

```
  xor eax, eax
  inc eax

  sub eax, eax
  inc eax
```

I can't immediately think of a two-byte sequence that would do the equivalent - I suspect there are none.

Answer (score 2):

```
mov $1, %eax
nop
```

Good enough for you? :)

If you really meant two bytes, not two opcodes, you may have a hard time with those constraints. I'd look at the surrounding code with an eye to whether there's anything you can take advantage of (eg, execute code in the middle of other code, etc). Or find a way to get more code space.

Comment: Good if i wanted like 10 opcodes :P Your example is actually 6 bytes. (intel syntax 'mov eax, 1')

Comment: 6 bytes but only 2 opcodes -- perhaps you meant to ask for 2 bytes not 2 opcodes?